# MongoDB PyMongo Listing all keys in a document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a question about how to manipulate a document in PyMongo to have it list all of its current keys, and I'm not quite sure how to do it. For example, if I had a document that looked like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectID("...")
    "name": ABCD,
    "info": {
        "description" : "XYZ",
        "type" : "QPR"
    }
}
```

and I had a variable "document" that had this current document as its value, how could I write code to print the three keys:

```
"_id"
"name"
"info"
```

I don't want it to list the values, simply the names. The motivation for this is that the user would type one of the names and my program would do additional things after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#documents):

> In PyMongo we use dictionaries to represent documents.

So you can get all keys using [`.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys):

```
print(document.keys())
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Is there a way to check first if the document has keys? Right now, if my document has no keys the program will crash

Comment: @DimiMak just `if document:`

Comment: what if the collection has different keys for different documents?

Answer (score 1):

Using Python we can do the following which is to fetch all the documents in a variable as mydoc

```
mydoc = collections.find()

for x in mydoc:
    l=list(x.keys())
    print(l)
```

Using this we can get all the keys as a list and then we can use them for further user's need

Answer (score -1):

the document is a python dictionary so you can just print its keys

e.g.

```
document = db.collection_name.find_one()
for k in document:
    print(k)
```